# How can I make a custom font-lock keyword regex?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, regular-expressions, font-lock

I'm new to emacs (spacemacs) and have been trying to get org-mode to highlight quoted strings `"like this"` and quoted strings `'like this'`. I followed [the example here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html), and came up with this:

```
  ;; Fancy custom syntax highlighting of quoted strings!
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\".*?\"" 1 font-lock-constant-face t)
                                            ("'.*?'" 1 font-lock-doc-face t)))))
```

This seems to break syntax highlighting all together, and doesn't succeed in higlighting my quoted strings at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a great series of articles on font lock by Sebastian Wiesner here: [1](https://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/syntactic-fontification-in-emacs), [2](https://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/advanced-syntactic-fontification), [3](https://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/search-based-fontification-with-keywords)

Comment: @izkon your links no longer work. Would it be possible to update these ?

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo -- See here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170501121925/http:/www.lunaryorn.com/series/emacs-font-locking.html

Answer (score 8):

For strings and comments it's better to use [syntactic fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntactic-Font-Lock.html). The syntax table for a given major mode has to be defined in variable `<major-mode-name>-syntax-table`.

This entry from the Emacs manual helps clarifying how Font Lock works: *Font Lock mode finds text to highlight in two ways: through syntactic parsing based on the syntax table, and through searching (usually for regular expressions). Syntactic fontification happens first; it finds comments and string constants and highlights them. Search-based fontification happens second.*

Now, there are a couple of problems with your code:

- Your regexp is badly written. To escape characters within a regexp string you have to use `\\`, so `"\".*?\""` should be `"\\".*?\\""`.
- Don't put the code on a hook, just add `(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode ...)` to your init file. Otherwise, whenever you enter Org mode you'll be adding that entry to `font-lock-keywords`.
- The fontification definition is badly writen. The number is used for groups, which you have none and so you should be using `("\\".*?\\"" 0 'font-lock-constant-face t)`. Read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html) of `font-lock-keywords` for further details. It's pretty helpful.
- If you need to use more complex regexps take a look at package `rx`.